# handling netbeans+symfony project on local network

Tags: netbeans, symfony1, project

We are two friends trying to develop an application on local network using symfony + netbeans + wamp.

I have shared wamp directory and put my wamp server online. Now my friend can work on project that is placed in my www directory but he can not access phpMyAdmin and when he opens 'run symfony commands' window by right clicking on project and then choosing 'symfony>run command', sm window tries to load symfony command but fails to load command and sm window remains empty.

How can we fix this problem? What is the proper way of working on a project on local area network?

Comment: phpbb?!? What does this have to do with symfony?

Comment: Ok next problems: what does "opens run" mean? What error(s) does he get when trying to acces pma? And when he tries to run symfony commands, how does he does this, using putty?

Comment: when he opens 'run symfony commands window' by right clicking on project and then choosing 'symfony>run command'

Comment: Ok I see... try running the commands from a normal cli windows, perhaps you'll get an error message? The project is stored on your machine, so I guess your friend does not have the rights to run the symfony executable on it. Make sure he does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me, a proper way of working on a project on a LAN would be to use two separate linux (could be installed on virtual machines if your reluctant to install it on real ones.) installations with two LAMP servers, and using a SCM tool like git, mercurial or svn to update code. Like this, you would not risk editing the same file, you would have a cool command line interface, and you would not have to deal with windows permissions.